# how to use bottom sheet transparent background in swiftui like dialog?

Tags: swiftui

I am using the bottom sheet. When the bottom opens, it covers the whole page over the parent. I want to use a bottom sheet like an alert dialog transparent. Thant means parent content not covered whole
here is the image:

[image]

The green portion is the content of the bottom sheet. But it covered the whole page.

Here is the code:

1. calling bottom sheet:

   ```
       struct CustomDialogSV: View {
       @State private var showSheet = false

           var body: some View {
               Button("Show Sheet") {
                   self.showSheet = true
               }
               .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                   ZStack {
                       Color.clear
                           .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                       CustomAlert()
                           .background(Color.red)
                           .cornerRadius(10)
                           .shadow(radius: 10)
                           .padding()
                         //  .center()
                   }
               }
           }
   }
   ```
2. Bottom sheet:

   ```
   struct CustomAlert: View {
        var body: some View {
           VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               Text("Alert Title")
                   .font(.headline)
                   .padding(.bottom)

               Text("This is the alert message. It can be any amount of text.")
                   .padding(.bottom)

               HStack {
                   Button(action: {
                       // handle action for first button
                   }) {
                       Text("First Button")
                   }
                   .padding(.trailing)

                   Button(action: {
                       // handle action for second button
                   }) {
                       Text("Second Button")
                   }
               }
           }
           .padding()
           .background(Color.green)
           .cornerRadius(10)
           .shadow(radius: 10)
       }
   }
   ```

Is it possible to remove the background without green portions?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. If you are using iOS 16.0+ you can use     `.presentationDetents([.medium, .large])` on your sheet. See here: https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-bottom-sheet/. Other than that if you want to display this as an alert, I would suggest using a `ZStack` which can be toggled an overlays the view.

Comment: @Tim Sorry for late reply. How to add dialog in swiftui?

Comment: I have found this resource online when searching for a custom dialog in Swift: https://yyokii.medium.com/swiftui-manage-custom-dialog-ac01668cae00. Hope this helps you to achieve a custom dialog in SwiftUI